# How to get score of a registered-query

Tags: xquery, server-side, marklogic

I'm trying to calculate a score for a complex match query.
For example:

```
if conditionA and conditionB and (conditionC or conditionD) 
then score = 10
else score = 0
```

This is the solution I've come up:

```
let $idReq := cts:register(
  cts:and-query((
   cts:path-range-query("/person/name", "=", 'val1', ("score-function=linear", "collation=http://marklogic.com/collation//S1")),
   cts:path-range-query("/person/country", "=", 'country', ("score-function=linear", "collation=http://marklogic.com/collation//S1")),
   cts:or-query((
     cts:path-range-query("/person/city", "=", 'city', ("score-function=linear", "collation=http://marklogic.com/collation//S1")),
     cts:path-range-query("/person/school", "=", '', ("score-function=linear", "collation=http://marklogic.com/collation//S1"))
   ))
 ))
)
return
  cts:score(cts:search(fn:doc(), cts:registered-query($idReq, ("unfiltered"), 10)))
```

All the indexes exists and the collation too.

When I execute this registered query, I always get 0 for the score.

**EDITED**

I've narrow down the problem , and it can reproduced by combining cts:register with cts:path-range-query.

```
let $query := cts:path-range-query("/person/name", "=", "val1", ("score-function=linear", "collation=http://marklogic.com/collation//S1"))
let $idReq := cts:register($query)
return 
  cts:score(
    cts:search(fn:doc(), 
      cts:registered-query($idReq,("unfiltered"), 10)
      (: $query :)
    )
  )
```

**EDITED**

Setup index config for testing:

```
import module namespace admin = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin" at "/MarkLogic/admin.xqy";

let $dbid := xdmp:database("Documents")
let $config := 
  admin:database-add-range-path-index(
    admin:get-configuration(), $dbid, 
    admin:database-range-path-index(
      $dbid, "string", "/person/name",
      "http://marklogic.com/collation//S1",
      fn:false(), "ignore"))
return admin:save-configuration($config)
```

Sample data:

```
xdmp:document-insert(
  '/test/person1.xml',
  <person>
    <name>val1</name>
    <city>city</city>
    <country>country</country>
  </person>
)
```

Comment: I ran your sample code (after a couple minor syntax fixes) in a database that had some matching results and I got a set of non-zero responses. Looks like you've simplified from your original. Do you get a list of zeros corresponding to the number of results?

Comment: Yes, i do get a list of zeros corresponding to the number of results. Maybe it's about database configuration?

Comment: I think I've simplified too much the query, I will edit my first post.

Comment: Not sure what's going on. [How a Range Query Contributes to Score](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/relevance#id_45213) says a range query (including path) can contribute if you add a scoring option, which you've done. I'll ask around.

Comment: Added sample config and data to make it easier for others to test.

Comment: Additional note: commenting out the registered query and running with just $query does provide a non-zero score. Haven't found anything in the docs about registered query scoring.